# Lightning Network snapshot via lncli describegraph only includes about half the network?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, umbrel

I pulled a snapshot of the Lightning Network via `lncli describegraph` with my Umbrel node in July 2022.

Everything worked fine and I analyzed the snapshot:

- ~18k nodes
- ~85k channels
- ~4k BTC total capacity

The results where similar to the data shown on 1ML, Amboss, etc.

However, I tried the same now multiple times in October 2022 and the snapshot only includes parts of the network:

- ~8k nodes
- ~30k channels
- ~2.3k BTC total capacity

([1ML](https://1ml.com/) and [Amboss](https://amboss.space/) currently show ~17k, ~82k, ~5k).

Any idea what might be the reason for this?

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I see a similar issue now. describegraph shows around 9.6k nodes and 32k channels, where 1ml is at 15k nodes and 62k channels.

Maybe this is related to how gossip works?